# can anyone explain why a4j:poll cannot reRender rich:dataTable?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam

This is my xhtml page:

```
<a:region>
    <h:form>
        <a:poll id="poll" interval="#{pollBean.pollInterval}"
            enabled="#{pollBean.pollEnabled}"
            timeout="#{pollBean.timeout}" reRender="poll,messagesList" />
    </h:form>
</a:region>
<h:form>
    <rich:dataTable id="messagesList" value="#{pollBean.messages}" var="message">
        <h:outputText value="#{message.content}" />
    </rich:dataTable>            
</h:form>
```

The rich:dataTable component does not rerendered after polling finished. After I use ui:repeat instead, it works fine. So can anyone explain this for me? Thanks.

My application is built on Seam 2.2.1.CR2 and richfaces 3.3.3 and deployed on JBoss 6.0.0.

Here is my simple PollBean.java:

```
@Name("pollBean")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Restrict("#{identity.loggedIn}")
public class PollBean implements Serializable {

    @In
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private boolean pollEnabled = true;

    private int pollInterval = 3000;

    private int timeout = 3000;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public PollBean() {
    }

    // getters and setters omitted

    /**
     * @return Returns a list of messages.
     */
    public List<Message> getMessages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Message> messages = this.entityManager.createQuery(
            "select message from Message message").getResultList();
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving everything in one form?

Comment: @JSS thats not an issue, multiple form should work

Comment: @JJ- Agree it shouldn't be but just wanted to chk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin,

Tested locally and code seems to be working fine so I suggest print all `pollBean` properties and debug it.

Comment: Thank you, JSS. Debugging shows that a4j:poll works well and pollBean.getMessages() is invoked as expected and no exception occurs, but rich:dataTable is still not re-rendered. Can you post your working code here?

Comment: This is my mistake. There is another component with the same id "messagesList" which is included by the template. After remove the duplicated id, rich:dataTable works.